# Does "none" have the same meaning as "nobody / no one"?

Tags: grammar

Does "none" have the same meaning as "nobody / no one" ? 
Example sentences: 
**Nobody (of us) can accomplish this.**
or
**None (of us) can accomplish this**

Answer (score 1):

It sometimes can. Using "None" is rather elevated and formal when used as a as direct replacement for "nobody".

In your particular example "Nobody can ..." and "None of us can..." are both fine. "None can ..." is rather formal in style, but still correct.
Instead of saying "None can" you use "None of ... can"

"Nobody of us can..." is not idiomatic, you could use "Nobody among us can.."